# "missing SET keyword" on hibernateTemplate bulkUpdate

Tags: java, hibernate, spring

My namedQuery:

```
@NamedQuery(name = "myUpdate", query = "update User set country = 'EN' where user.id = ?")
```

In service layer:

```
Query query = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession.getNamedQuery("myUpdate");
getHibernateTemplate.bulkUpdate(query.getQueryString(), id);
```

I get an error:

Hibernate: update User, set country=EN where id = 2343
ORA-00971: missing SET keyword

Anybody now how can resolve this problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to update data using hibernate query having parent property in where clause](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16436606/how-to-update-data-using-hibernate-query-having-parent-property-in-where-clause)

Comment: I've flagged it as a duplicated 'coz I found the answer in: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16438031/3120564

Answer (score 0):

Did you specify the oracle dialect in the hibernate.cfg.xml file? The named queries you provide are translated by Hibernate into a DB-specific query. If the dialect is wrong, the translations produces SQL which a may be wrong for the target database.

See the comma in `update User, set`?

Comment: 1. I set hibernate dialect to org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect. I saw a comma. I have no idea where to take there.

Comment: What do you think, where does that comma?

Comment: I've got the same problem in Hibernate 4 and I do have specified `<property name="hibernate.dialect"                                value="org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect"/>`. in persistence.xml.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there is a limitation in Hibernate regarding bulk update and implicit/explicit joins.
I found a solution at
http://www.techques.com/question/1-5368522/Why-this-hibernate-template-bulkUpdate-doesn't-work