# how to update data using hibernate query having parent property in where clause

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate

I am working on java web application using hibernate and oracle.I have set two entities like this

```
    @Entity
    public class Student{
    @Id
    Long id;
    String name;
    }

    @Entity
    public class Exam{
    @Id
    Long id;
    String status;
    @ManyToOne
    Student student;
    }
```

When I use select query in hibernate like this

```
    String hql="from Exam exam where exam.student.name=:name"
```

It works fine
but when i use update query in hibernate like this

```
    String hql="update Exam exam set status=:status where exam.student.name=:name"
```

It produce following error

```
    org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: ORA-00971: missing SET keyword

at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:122)
at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:125)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:110)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.AbstractStatementProxyHandler.continueInvocation(AbstractStatementProxyHandler.java:129)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.AbstractProxyHandler.invoke(AbstractProxyHandler.java:81)
at $Proxy154.executeUpdate(Unknown Source)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.exec.BasicExecutor.execute(BasicExecutor.java:103)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.executeUpdate(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:413)
at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performExecuteUpdate(HQLQueryPlan.java:282)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.executeUpdate(SessionImpl.java:1267)
at org.hibernate.internal.QueryImpl.executeUpdate(QueryImpl.java:116)
```

am I doing something wrong?

Comment: is the status field mapped to anything ?

Comment: did you try `update Exam exam set exam.status=:status where exam.student.name=:name` ?

Comment: no. it is not mapped to anything.

Comment: sanbhat: Ya I tried that.

Answer (score 1):

Check if u have getters and setters. 
Also use annotation `@Column` if name is in database:

```
@Entity
    public class Student{
    @Id
    Long id;
    @Column(name="studentName")
    String name;
    }
```

If u have some "identification flags" which are not mapped to database table use `@Transient` which means:http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/Transient.html

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer.

According to http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/batch.html#batch-direct

No joins, either implicit or explicit, can be specified in a bulk HQL query. Sub-queries can be used in the where-clause, where the subqueries themselves may contain joins.

So to solve my problem I updated my query to

```
    String hql = "update Exam exam set exam.status=:status where exam.id in(select e.id from Exam e where e.student.name=:name)"
```

Answer (score 0):

Get an object and try modify its value and update it.

`Query q = session.createQuery("from Exam  exam where exam.student.name=:name");
   q.setParameter("name", "xyz");

   Exam exam = (Exam)q.list().get(0);`

exam. status("completed");
   session.update(exam);

Use this if you are sure you get one and only one recored to be updated. other wise you can implement using this for your requirement